# Finding c1, c2 and c3 for a matrix using eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A 3 by 3 matrix A has eigenvalues and eigenvectors:
$$
Ax_1 = x_1, Ax_2 = 2x_2, Ax_3 = 3x_3$$ Suppose
$$
b = 4x_1 + 5x_2 + 6x_3$$

a. Find

$$y = c_1x_1 + c_2x_2 + c_3x_3$$ so that:
$$
A^2
y − 3Ay + 4y = b$$
(Find c1, c2, c3)

I thought I could solve this by replacing $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$ for their eigenvalue counterparts in the equation for y and then solving for b, but I still have no idea how to fully solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Note that $$Ay = A(c_1x_1+c_2x_2+c_3x_3) = c_1Ax_1+c_2Ax_2+c_3Ax_3 = c_1x_1+2c_2x_2+3c_3x_3,$$ and that $$A^2y = A(Ay) = A(c_1x_1+2c_2x_2+3c_3x_3) = c_1Ax_1+2c_2Ax_2+3c_3Ax_3 = c_1x_1+4c_2x_2+9c_3x_3.$$

Can you write both sides of the equation $A^2y-3Ay+4y = b$ as a linear combination of $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$? After doing this, since $A$ has three distinct eigenvalues, the eigenvectors are linearly independent. So two linear combinations of $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ are equal if and only if the coefficients of $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ are equal.

Comment: thank you so much!